# Can Internet Explorer send cookies from Flash?

Tags: javascript, php, flash, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a webpage that embeds a flash widget that sends AJAX POSTs.  I use PHP to interpret these on the server.

The problem is that Internet Explorer doesn't send the "Cookie" HTTP header from the requests generated in the Flash, so I'm unable to pick up my PHP session on the server.

Chrome and FF do send the Cookie header from inside the flash.

I've tried the P3P headers and browser security settings changes.

Does anyone know if this is possible within IE? I can't change the flash, so would have to be a browser setting, or ideally, some HTTP change...

Comment: You can't change the Flash but do you have the code that sends the 'cookie'?

Comment: No, it's actually generated from Articulate Storyline.  I was hoping it goes through the usual flash HTTP APIs, so the browser has some control over it.  The fact that it works in FF and not in IE would lead me to believe that, but I'm guessing a bit. There's not much I can do to drill into that. All can see is the output in Firebug (etc) when the requests have been sent...

Answer (score -1):

If its a problem with IE you can probably fix it for yourself by installing the newest version of IE and Flash on your computer.  Other people are probably going to have trouble with it however.  I really don't know what you are talking about with "Cookie" header but I don't see why that would stop you from handling a request if it is getting sent.  If you wanted to post the code that is handling the request that would probably be helpful.

In reality, you probably shouldn't be using a Flash solution to handle your ajax requests.